# Maximum in a List

Tags: prolog

I have a list and each element of the list has five components, so the list would be something like [[1,3,4,5,6], [2,4,5,15,16],...].
I want to find the maximum of the third component of all elements in the list. I am using the following routine but it does not work:

```
maxList([_,_,_,_,_],Max).   
maxList([_,_,A,_,_|F],Max):- A>=Max, Max1=A, maxList(F,Max1).  
maxList([_,_,A,_,_|F],Max):- A<Max, Max1=Max, maxList(F,Max1).
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not treat the first parameter as a list of lists - rather, it treats it as a list of five elements.

Here is how you can fix this:

```
maxList([[_,_,Max,_,_]], Max). /* List of one element */
maxList([[_,_,A,_,_]|F], Max):- maxList(F, B), Max is max(A, B).
```

This solution uses built-in [`max/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=max/2).

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/pd5hju).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improved version (does not create any choice-point and the recursion is terminal). For this it uses an auxiliary predicate with an accumulator. NB: only the 3 first elements of the lists are "matched".

```
maxList([[_,_,X|_]|L], Max) :-
    maxList(L, X, Max).

maxList([], Max, Max).
maxList([[_,_,X|_]|L], Max, Max2):-
    Max1 is max(X, Max),
    maxList(L, Max1, Max2).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
maxList(L,Max) :-
    select([_,_,Max,_,_], L, L1), \+ (member([_,_,M,_,_], L1), M > Max).
```

CapelliC gives the template of the solution in a previous thread.